Problem with loading js scripts using php,smarty,js
I don't even know how to describe this problem.
Let's say that I have template in smarty with code (part) :
 <div class="view-choice-container">
      <span>Widok:</span>
      <div class="choices-box">
            <img data-choice="compact" src="media/build/img/compact-view.svg" alt="Widok kompaktowy" class="icon viewChoiceJs"/>
            <img data-choice="normal-view" src="media/build/img/normal-view.svg" alt="Widok normalny" class="icon viewChoiceJs icon--active"/>
      </div>
 </div>

This is visible in html structure when the page renders.
Next I have js script like this :
export default () => {
    // get all view choice elements by class viewChoiceJs
    const choices = document.querySelectorAll('.viewChoiceJs');
    // console.log(choices)
    console.log(choices.length)
    if (choices.length === 0) {
        return;
    }
    choices.forEach(function (choice) {
        // add event listener to each view choice element
        choice.addEventListener('click', function () {
            // get the view choice value
            const viewChoice = this.getAttribute('data-choice');
            // remove icon--active class from all view choice elements
            choices.forEach(function (choice) {
                choice.classList.remove('icon--active');
            });
            // add icon--active class to the clicked view choice element
            this.classList.add('icon--active');
        });
    });
}


This script then is called by "mother" script like so:
import filtersPanel from "./components/filtersPanel";
import viewChoice from "./components/viewChoice";
import ulubioneButton from "./components/ulubioneButton";

window.addEventListener('load', () => {
    console.log('Document loaded');
    viewChoice();
    ulubioneButton();
})

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    console.log('Document ready');
    filtersPanel();
})

// window.onload = function () {
//     console.log('Window loaded');
//     viewChoice();
//     ulubioneButton();
// }

I have tried to call it in these three different functions.
Then this Mother script is compiled by gulp and plugged to header along bunch of other scripts.
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/media/build/js/main.min.js?v={$tmplWebVersion}"></script>
</head>

Now the problem is that this script should always console log number 2 because I have 2 imgs with class viewChoiceJs but the outcome is that when I restart PC, on the first load I get 2 and any other refresh after it always returns 0...

What's funnier is that for my colleague on his Opera browser it always works, but for his Firefox the behaviour is the same, first load 2 then any other 0.
I also opened chrome on the server and 6 out of 10 loads were successfull.
On my mobile phone every 2nd load is successfull...
What am I doing wrong ? Is it browser issue ? Is it somehow script loading "moment" issue ? Am I Plugging it in the wrong place ? Maybe there's other function that checks if everything is loaded and only then runs script ?
I'm doing exactly the same for arrows for filters (at least it appears that way) :
export default () => {
    document.querySelectorAll('.filter-arrow-icon').forEach(function (arrowIcon) {
        arrowIcon.addEventListener('click', function () {
            const filterBox = this.closest('.filter-inner').querySelector('.filter-box');
            if (filterBox) {
                filterBox.classList.toggle('hidden');
                this.classList.toggle('rotate-svg');
            }
        });
    });
}

And this works every time without problems.

Why is the v query parameter changing with each page load?

The issue likely stems from the timing of when the DOM elements are available versus when your script is being executed. To ensure the elements are available, consider wrapping your script in a function that checks if the DOM is fully loaded and all elements are present before executing the logic. Additionally, ensure your script is included at the end of the body or within a DOMContentLoaded event.

@FarrukhNaveedAnjum I think you need to look more closely at OP's code, in particular window.addEventListener('load', and document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',

@Phil hey, it's just some parameter variable, it doesn't influence the script itself. I can as well remove it from the tag and things stays the same

Use your browser's dev-tools to put a breakpoint on the console.log(choices.length) line (or just add debugger; into your JS code) and inspect the state of the document while it's paused
